# extracting webpage content through php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse and process HTML with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php)

```
<body> 
    <table align="center">

<?
 $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $url=file_get_contents("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ip");
 preg_match_all('/<th>(.*?)<\/th><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$url,$output,PREG_SET_ORDER);
 for ($q=0; $q < 25; $q++) {
    if ($output[$q][1]) {
        if (!stripos($output[$q][2],"Blacklist")) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$output[$q][1]."</td><td>".$output[$q][2]."</td></tr>";

        }
    }
}
?> 
    </table>
</body>
```

Now, with this code I get a lot of information like isp,country, etc.

How can I extract the content so that I load them into my database like $country , $isp , etc? I think it can be done if it's converted to xml but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**

Using that you can :

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');
```

and later from html using functions defined in parser like find and others get individual tags..

[Read this](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: would you will give me little example ... sample code ... i cant understand

Comment: Dude read on the link i've given there are many examples...read documentation for more..

Comment: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm